# ParseLong NumberFormat exception error

Tags: java, algorithm

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "110101001011101110001111100110001010100001101011101010000011011011001011101111001100000011011110011";
        long sum = Long.parseLong(s, 2);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Why do I get a `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: Because it is Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong

Comment: Your string `s` easily goes beyond what long data type can hold!

Comment: A `long` is 64 bits. You're specifying 99 bits. `99 > 64`.

Comment: Someone gave `BigInteger` as anwer but it was just removed by some reason. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Long dimension is 64 bit, so max binary string can't be more than 64 length (you have 100). You can split your data on several 64-bit parts and collect list of `Long` values.

Or you can use BigInteger:

```
BigInteger val = new BigInteger("110101001011101110001111100110001010100001101011101010000011011011001011101111001100000011011110011", 2);
System.out.println(val.toString()); // prints '526700554598729746900966573811'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at attached page and see what is the max and min value for specific types. Try with BigInteger as someone suggested.

[Java basic data types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NumberFormatException` because the number `110101001011101110001111100110001010100001101011101010000011011011001011101111001100000011011110011` is far too large to be stored within a `long` in Java.

For reference, the max value for a `long` in Java is 9223372036854775807 in decimal. In binary, this is 111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111, which is less than:

1101 0100 1011 1011 1000 1111 1001 1000 1010 1000 0110 1011 1010 1000 0011 0110 1100 1011 1011 1100 1100 0000 1101 1110 011.

Answer (score -1):

Your String is too long ;-)
Check out Long.MAX_VALUE